# TS2339: Property does not exist on type {}

Tags: typescript, flux, alt.js

Please help me fix this compilation error.

Below you can see the compiler complaining that the **Actions** object on line 20 (I removed a few lines for clarity before posting this) is {}:
[image]

But below you can see in **actions.ts** that **Actions** is an object of type **Actions**, and it has the requested property (which is a function):
[image]

And in the base code you can see in the DefinitelyTyped **Alt** definition that **createActions** should return an object of type **Actions**:
[image]

So why is Typescript complaining that Actions is not of type Actions?

Comment: This was hard to read! In the future, please paste your code directly, and maybe mark relevant parts using comments like `// HERE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a module called `"app/actions/actions"`. That module is actually not a module (a map of properties), but whatever's the result of `flux.createACtions(Actions)`:

```
export = flux.createActions(Actions); // in actions.ts
```

What does that return? Because you're not specifying the generic for `<T>`, and because the params of `createActions` don't correctly include a `T` from which it could infer, it assumes that `T` is just `{}`. This was [discussed here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/360) and ultimately declined. So, as mentioned, you need to specify the generic:

```
export = flux.createActions<Actions>(Actions);
```

But to avoid this, you could change your local (or remote) `alt.d.ts` to be something like:

```
class Alt {
    createActions<T extends ActionsClass>(con: ActionsClassConstructor<T>, ...): T;
}
type ActionsClassConstructor<T extends ActionsClass> = new (alt:Alt) => T;
```

This adds the generic type info needed to correctly infer based on the constructor you supply.