# How to correctly create class members?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I inherited code, and I am trying to get it transpiled and eventually running. Within a `components/TableAsset.tsx` I found the following lines

```
import { Table } from "antd";
const { Column, ColumnGroup } = Table;
class MyTable extends Table<Interfaces.ViewEntry> { }
```

This gives various [typescript errors, which I do not understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58446753/). But what might have actually be intended with this piece of code? How would you write it in today's Typescript 3.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what might have actually be intended with this piece of code?

That code:

1. [Imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) a *named export* called `Table` from `"antd"`:

```
import { Table } from "antd";
```

2. Uses [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to assign `Table.Column` and `Table.ColumnGroup` to the constants `Column` and `ColumnGroup`, respectively:

```
const { Column, ColumnGroup } = Table;
```

3. Creates a class that extends `Table`, providing `Interfaces.ViewEntry` for `Table`'s *generic parameter* (more: [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)):

```
class MyTable extends Table<Interfaces.ViewEntry> { }
```

> How would you write it in today's Typescript 3.x?

That code is just fine for TypeScript 3.x.